# Populate unique ID in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make my ID in class Animal unique, so that it automatically increments without a user having to add data into the filed (so the filed is hidden), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Right now I have this in my `models.py`:

```
 class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Which in my mind will have to make id unique, but currently it doesn't do anything.

Here is my `serialisers.py` for reference:

```
class AnimalSerialiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    doctor = DoctorSerealiser(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ('id' , 'name' , 'gender' , 'breed' , 'adoption' , 'vaccines', 'doctor')
```

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't do anything'?

Comment: So it displays the field and I can leave out the Id and it will show as `" "` in my table and database

Comment: Why are you using UUID as primarykey? why not the normal AutoField?

Comment: @v1k45 no particular reason, but when I use AutioField it gives me this error `'AutoField' object has no attribute 'model'`

Comment: Well, you aren't required to set the `id` field by yourself. If you don't create `id` field, it'll automatically increment its value based on DB. Also, using UUID as PK is a bad idea imo.

Comment: @v1k45 so you mean that even if i dont create an id, the db will create it for me? If so, how can i get it to display it on my Rest List page?

Comment: yep, django creates an autofield named `id` for you. you can access in your pages by using field name `id`

Comment: @v1k45, can you explain please what's wrong with using UUID as PK? Isn't it better than a predictable auto-incrementing key?

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned in the comments, you're defining your model wrong. Django adds an auto-incrementing field by default. Take a look at the docs for more information - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields.

You really just need:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and then you can still access that field like `animal.id`.

And UUID's are totally different than an auto-incrementing ID. See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) - they're basically just strings that are nearly impossible to generate duplicates of.

Comment: tried what you suggested, but getting this error `'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.`

Comment: @user3395936 - have you either migrated or deleted and recreated your database?